# Why are my transactions not processing?

Tags: operation

I'm trying to use TRD to make rewards payments. I can see that everything is forged, signed, and pre-apply'd correctly. Then injected correctly. I get an op-hash. But then nothing. Op never shows up. I can look at my node's mempool:

```
{ "hash": "oovZc2HLBU86KwZEPmXVn8h5NcdEYceQNbWBvJ9Hw5Dm6QTU9wE",
    "branch": "BMFW1ST7VBRov5mgrtBMQnkHRqmggi9HthZUb3HYG4DZw8vXXac",
    "contents":
      [ { "kind": "transaction",
          "source": "tz1TDSDUUe2Pc5UqR7ZKmyS5URaL6EdtEh1b",
          "fee": "1792", "counter": "558902", "gas_limit": "15385",
          "storage_limit": "0", "amount": "19327514",
          "destination": "KT1PZTCay6N95deh6bHTvhjEUmb9nHsf9heV" } ],
    "signature":
      "sigY7oTHFsGFkp4eHmebaZWxrRQUc8AfdYLxHw8H6q9PDF95ifHzfP8K7Fi1QQumBveVjyJanqHmtUoK4wbBbHvikKsj1hA8" },
  { "hash": "ong9ZnhMib79m27uY4in2LeomNVtKzyp41EjqYZryoi9hqspbu5",
    "branch": "BMFW1ST7VBRov5mgrtBMQnkHRqmggi9HthZUb3HYG4DZw8vXXac",
    "contents":
      [ { "kind": "transaction",
          "source": "tz1RV1MBbZMR68tacosb7Mwj6LkbPSUS1er1",
          "fee": "2941", "counter": "73169", "gas_limit": "44725",
          "storage_limit": "300", "amount": "100645594",
          "destination": "KT1RojGTFumrTgX8SmTMysWqqbN3cdBg1PLe" },
        { "kind": "transaction",
          "source": "tz1RV1MBbZMR68tacosb7Mwj6LkbPSUS1er1",
          "fee": "2941", "counter": "73170", "gas_limit": "44725",
          "storage_limit": "300", "amount": "31490471",
          "destination": "KT1VMAUzJ6PoGkLbudT6ByPycDfzwKmUtJXa" },
```

There are two operations. My operation, ong9Z, contains about 40 transactions in 1 batch. The one above is a single transaction. We both have the same branch. My fee, storage, and gas are significantly higher than the other. Yet, my trx will remain in mempool and never make it out. The other op was processed within a few seconds and is visible on the chain.
What could possibly be preventing my transactions from processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was some issue with my node. After stopping my node, wiping the datadir, and importing a post-Babylon snapshot provided by another baker, the same transaction, with no modifications to fee/gas, processed right away.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when your specs for gas and fees are evaluated against each other and your desired transaction, the baker deems it not worth it.  Also you probably don't need storage limit 300 either, you can probably just use 0?